# Hibernate count from multi tables

Tags: hibernate, count

I would like to write a single HQL query that return a specific count from 4 tables in different columns.

I have 4 tables: `Tab1`, `Tab2`, `Tab3` and `Tab4`, and I would like to get something like this:

```
|Tab1   | Tab2  | Tab3  | Tab4   |
|..1....|..13...|...7...|....0...|
```

All records in `Tab#`s have their own `id` and `ObjectID` and `ObjectFetch`columns

I have tried something like this:

```
select DISTINCT
(select count(*) from Tab1 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
(select count(*) from Tab2 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
(select count(*) from Tab3 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
(select count(*) from Tab4 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
from Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4
```

But it doesn't work at all, any idea why?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Express, but is it matters ?

Comment: Well, whould suggest you to use a native query to solve your problem, if you have no HQL based answers.

Comment: Thank you, understand. But if in the future i have similar problem that answer is HQL based it would be a nice example. Thx one more time, but if you or someone else know the HQL for something like this it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, simply there is no need to use all tables after `FROM` we can use only 1, it is just for a correct syntax, also we can use a virtualTable, so the right HQL

```
select DISTINCT
(select count(*) from Tab1 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
(select count(*) from Tab2 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
(select count(*) from Tab3 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id),
(select count(*) from Tab4 where ObjectFetch=:fetch and ObjectID=:id)
from Tab1
```

and its all ok :) thx.